# Grails using dynamic finders with 3x+ logical arguments

Tags: grails, dynamic, finder

I sucessfully managed to search in the database using this dynamic finder from Hibernate:

```
def temp = User.findByNameAndStreet("name", "street")
```

Although, i need a tripple logical argument like this:

```
def temp = User.findByNameAndStreetAndCity("name", "street", "city")
```

Any simple way to do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Grails dynamic finders don't support more than two predicates. This is because it's not clear whether

```
User.findByNameAndAgeOrGender('foo', 12, 'm')
```

means this:

```
(name == 'foo' && age == 12) || gender == 'm'
```

or this:

```
name == 'foo' && (age == 12 || gender == 'm')
```

Admittedly if the predicates are always combined with `And` or `Or`.

---

**Update**: since Grails 1.4 you can have an unlimited number of predicates if they're all combined with either `And` or `Or`

---

Instead, you can use either `findWhere` or `findAllWhere` (depending on whether you want just the first result or all results). Both of these support an unlimited number of predicates which I assume are combined with `And`, for example:

```
User.findAllWhere(name: "foo", age: 12, gender: 'm')
```

Comment: `findWhere` and `findAllWhere` or Criteria/HQL queries are the way to go when you need more than 2. The reason for the limit of 2 is just to avoid absurdly long method names, but this limitation has been removed in 1.4. To avoid confusion about order of resolution you can't mix `and`/`or` - they have to all be `and` or all `or`, but it's simple enough to do a real query if you need to mix `and` and `or`.