# searching values by using dynamic finders in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to search using dynamic finders by two fields which are `status` and `OpenOn(date)`. This query is working well and fine:

```
 render(view:'list', model:[incidentInstanceList:Incident.findAllByStatusIlikeAndOpenOnGreaterThan("closed",new Date()-1,[sort:"id",order:"desc"])])
```

But now I'm trying to search with dynamic finders by three fields, i.e. `UserId`,`status` and `OpenOn(date)`:

```
 render(view:'list', model:[incidentInstanceList:Incident.findAllByStatusIlikeuserIdIlikeAndOpenOnGreaterThan("closed","${session.user.userId}",new Date()-1,[sort:"id",order:"desc"])])
```

This query does not work properly and shows an error:

```
No signature of method: app.Incident.findAllByStatusIlikeuserIdIlikeAndOpenOnGreaterThan() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, java.util.Date, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [closed, tt10004, Wed Aug 24 15:12:21 IST 2011, [sort:id, order:desc]] Possible solutions: findAllByStatusIlikeuserIdIlikeAndCreatedOnGreaterThan(java.util.List)
```

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def incidentInstanceList = {

    def criteria = Incident.createCriteria()

    def results = criteria {
        and {
            user {
                like('userId', "${session.user.userId}").toString()
            }
            like('status',  "Closed" ) 
            gt('closedOn',new Date()-1)
            sort("id", "desc")
        }  

    } 

    render(view:'list', model:[ incidentInstanceList: results, incidentInstanceTotal: Incident.count()])        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, you can only use dynamic finders with a maximum of **two** criteria. If you need to use more, you should consider using either [Criteria](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/single.html#5.4.2%20Criteria) or the [HQL](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/single.html#5.4.3%20Hibernate%20Query%20Language%20%28HQL%29).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360547/grails-using-dynamic-finders-with-3x-logical-arguments/6360858#6360858) goes into more detail on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this, which, by the way, seems more legible for me:

```
def incidentInstanceList = 
    Incident.createCriteria().list
    {
        eq(status, 'closed')
        ilike(userId, "${session.user.userId}")
        gt(openOn, new Date()-1)
        sort("id", "desc")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides i think there is no need to put second parameter "" just do session.user.userId (i assume u don`t need userId to be String here) [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) is what u need :)